# Spring boot @OneToMany association saves id with null value

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

- > Hello guys i don't know why but when i tried to define an association
  > @one to many i get a null in the service_id and question_id.

> first entity

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Services implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;
    private String serviceName;
    private String description;
    private String image;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Questions> questions;
```

> Second entity

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Questions implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;
    private String question;

    @Column(name="service_id")
    private String service_id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Answers> answers;
```

> third entity

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Answers implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;
    private String answer;
    private double cost;

    @Column(name="question_id")
    private String question_id;
```

> you can find the image for the tables bellow

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZtAx.png)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is remove the following line from Both of your models:

```
@Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
```

After this line: `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`

That will solve your problem.

Comment: i tried it but it didn't work

Comment: when exactly you get null value ? Can explain a bit more?